# What is the Haversine equation measured in for DBSCAN analysis in RapidMiner?

Tags: parameters, cluster-analysis, distance, rapidminer, dbscan

When I am using the DBSCAN clustering algorithm in RapidMiner, I am not sure of what value the Haversine equation uses as an epsilon. The dataset I am currently working with is coded in latitude and longitude degrees.  I want the measurement to ideally measure distance in 200 meters.  What would I need to include under epsilon for this to work?

[image: dbscan epsilon setting]

Comment: go ahead and include a link to your image, someone will edit your question and include it. :)

Comment: Good call, user Barett!  Link is now included.

Comment: Have you looked at the source code? Or can't you infer from your dendrogram what scale Rapidminer users? I have only used ELKI: it uses meters, and the indexes are really fast for such data.

Comment: Thank you to user Barett for embedding the image!

@Anony-Mousse, btoh of the above.  I unfortunately do not know how to access the source code for RapidMiner, and the FAQ only gives a vague description of epsilon as "This parameter specifies the epsilon parameter of the DBSCAN algorithm. epsilon specifies the size of the neighborhood. Range: real".  While this is not inaccurate, it seems like it is applicable only for known units of distances.   I do not know what the output is is latitudinal/longitudinal decimal degrees are included.

Comment: https://github.com/rapidminer/rapidminer except that they only publish ancient versions of rapidminer as opensource... Also beware that the order `lat,lng` or `lng,lat` is not consistently used everywhere. If you swap them, results will be chaos. So you *really* need to find their documentation on their Haversine distance! (NOT the dbscan documentation!) E.g. [ELKI haversine distance says they use meters](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/releases/release0.6.5~20141030/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/distance/distancefunction/geo/LngLatDistanceFunction.html), and they have versions for each parameter order.

Answer (score 0):

The haversine distance is not part of the normal set of distance functions provided by RapidMiner.
Do you have by chance installed any Extensions that provide that include this distance?
If so, you have to check their  documentation or source code.